# Reading comprehension question

Tags: reading-comprehension

Can you help me regarding the following question related to the paragraph below. For me, all the options can be answer because each option contains a non-text and text information.

> Furthermore, very often today words and images of various sorts are
>   juxtaposed and integrated in a variety of ways. In newspaper and
>   magazines as well as in textbooks, images take up more and more of the
>   space alongside words. In fact, in many modern high school and college
>   textbooks in the sciences images not only take up more space, they now
>   carry meanings that are independent of the words in the text. If you
>   can't read these images, you will not be able to recover their
>   meanings from the words in the text as was more usual in the past. In
>   such multimodal texts (texts that mix words and images), the images
>   often communicate different things from the words.

An example from a science textbook of the phenomenon the author describes in the third paragraph could be

A) A genetic tree that coincides with the discussion of specific mammal classes in the text

B) A diagram of a specific chemical reaction that is used to explain a broad definition in the text

C) An illustration of a plant cycle that accompanies a chapter on photosynthesis

D) A cartoon that references the same methods discussed in the text about laboratory safety

Comment: Is this a "bad" question?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the passage is to explain how some textbooks have images that teach *new* information rather than simply illustrating the same concepts in the text.

A) **Wrong** because the illustration "coincides with" the text. Nothing new

D) **Wrong** because the cartoon references "the same" methods in the text.

But between B) and C), I don't know. C) illustrates the plant cycle, which is more information than simply photosynthesis. However why isn't the illustration about the plant cycle in a chapter about the plant cycle? It seems out of place and not like it would teach you anything. B) seems to closely match the passage where it says,

> If you can't read these images, you will not be able to recover their meanings from the words in the text as was more usual in the past.